# How to mix a module into an rspec context

Tags: ruby, rspec2, ruby-1.9

How can I mix a module into an rspec context (aka `describe`), such that the module's constants are available to the spec?

```
module Foo
  FOO = 1
end

describe 'constants in rspec' do

  include Foo

  p const_get(:FOO)    # => 1
  p FOO                # uninitialized constant FOO (NameError)

end
```

That `const_get` can retrieve the constant when the name of the constant cannot is interesting.  What's causing rspec's curious behavior?

I am using MRI 1.9.1 and rspec 2.8.0.  The symptoms are the same with MRI 1.8.7.

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use RSpec's `shared_context`:

```
shared_context 'constants' do
  FOO = 1
end

describe Model do
  include_context 'constants'

  p FOO    # => 1
end
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I learned a new cool thing about rspec. Very nice.

Answer (score 12):

You want `extend`, not `include`. This works in Ruby 1.9.3, for instance:

```
module Foo
  X = 123
end

describe "specs with modules extended" do
  extend Foo
  p X # => 123
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to reuse an RSpec context across different tests, use `shared_context`:

```
shared_context "with an apple" do
  let(:apple) { Apple.new }
end

describe FruitBasket do
  include_context "with an apple"

  it "should be able to hold apples" do
    expect { subject.add apple }.to change(subject, :size).by(1)
  end
end
```

If you want to reuse specs across different contexts, use `shared_examples` and `it_behaves_like`:

```
shared_examples "a collection" do
  let(:collection) { described_class.new([7, 2, 4]) }

  context "initialized with 3 items" do
    it "says it has three items" do
      collection.size.should eq(3)
    end
  end
end

describe Array do
  it_behaves_like "a collection"
end

describe Set do
  it_behaves_like "a collection"
end
```

Comment: I tried `extend` too, but I still got a `NameError`. Even stranger, when I tried `include Foo` and `p(constants - Object.constants)`, the constant `X` is clearly in the list, but I can't reference it directly — only through `const_get`. This is Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: In 1.8.7, `extend` works a little differently in the RSpec context. I'm on 1.9.3.

Comment: @John, neither MRI 1.8.7 nor MRI 1.9.1 work with the `extend` solution.  What version of rspec are you using?

Comment: best answer I've found on using shared context thank you