# How to permit unqualified access to constants of a module in Rspec tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec

### Would like to include constants from a module in RSpec examples.

This question is looking for a way to permit unqualified referencing of constants from a module in rspec 3.9 examples. This is mostly to save space and typing.

```rb
module MyConsts
  FOO = "foo"
end

RSpec.describe "Tests Module Constants" do
  it 'has unqualified access to constants.' do
    expect(FOO).to eq("foo") 
  end
end
```

### Approaches that do not work:

#### [RSpec::Core::Configuration#include](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec%2FCore%2FConfiguration:include) does not pick up constants.

It is a convenient way to [include helper functions from module](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module#include-a-module-in-all-example-groups), but it's not the same as using include on a class in that the constants aren't available as expected.

```rb
module MyConsts
  FOO = "foo"
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include MyConsts
end

RSpec.describe "Tests Module Constants" do
  it 'has qualified access to constants.' do
    expect(MyConsts::FOO).to eq("foo")
  end

  it 'has unqualified access to constants.' do
    expect(FOO).to eq("foo") 
  end
end
```

The unqualified access example fails.  It would be nice to be able to mix in the constants from the module so examples like that do pass.

```
Failures:
  1) Tests Module Constants has unqualified access to constants.
     Failure/Error: expect(FOO).to eq("foo")

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant FOO
```

#### Using include within the `describe` block does not work.

From a previously [closed issue of rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/41) one might be led to believe using include within the `describe` block would work.  It does not.

```rb
module MyConsts
  FOO = "foo"
end

RSpec.describe "Tests Module Constants" do
  include MyConsts

  it 'has unqualified access to constants.' do
    expect(FOO).to eq("foo") 
  end
end
```

#### Copying all the constants is a non-starter

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141517/1180551) to a very similar question suggests using a [`shared_context`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/example-groups/shared-context).  While it does produce the end result, it would require duplicating the constants definitions. That is a problem as there are hundreds of them, the constants module is pulled from another project entirely, and keeping them up to date is too much work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to define your RSpec tests in the context of the module:

```
module MyConsts
  FOO = "foo"
end

module MyConsts
  RSpec.describe "Tests Module Constants" do
    it "has unqualified access to constants." do
      expect(FOO).to eq("foo")
    end
  end
end
```

RSpec.describe defines a module, and if it's defined as a child of MyConsts, then constant lookups will bubble up to MyConsts.

You could also just mix MyConsts in at the top level:

```
include MyConsts
```

This approach may be less desirable, as it would make those consts usable from *anywhere*, making them effectively global, which may be leakier than you'd like.